# $wpdb->get_var isn't working for me

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am working on a paypal IPN handler that gets an IPN then sends an e-mail.  Right now I am testing it trying to access the 'paid' column of my database to make sure the transaction has not already previously been processed.  However $wpdb doesn't seem to be returning things correctly.  I was able to use $wpdb on another form to insert things into the database but I am having trouble getting it back out.  I have tried get_var, get_row, and get_results and tried to access them as objects, arrays, or a variable in the case of get_var.

```
$paidstatus = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT paid FROM wp_bbbiller WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'");

$subject = 'Test e-mail';
$message = "Thank you for your purchase $payer_email. Your total was $".$payment_amount."     for $duration hour 
    with $usercount users.  Previously paid: $paidstatus";

mail ($payer_email , $subject , $message);
```

Right now the $paidstatus shows up blank in the e-mail.  I tried using print_r($paidstatus) when I had it setup with get_row and it showed up as a '1' in the email, even though the database value is 0.

Comment: I should add that I already have declared $wpdb as a global earlier in the script.

Comment: Can you show your wp_bbbiller schema?

Comment: Not sure I know what you mean?  txn_id is a varchar(13) and paid is a tinyint(1).  Using paid as a 0/1 false/true type deal.

Comment: have you double-checked that there is a row in wp_bbbiller with the txn_id that you're using in the query? And that it has been created before you are querying for it? I can't think of anything else.

Comment: Yes I have.  I only have one entry in the database as I am just testing everything atm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes using get_results works!  I was able to access the variable like this

```
$paidstatus = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT paid FROM wp_bbbiller WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'");

foreach ($paidstatus as $status) {
    $subject = 'Test e-mail';
    $message = "Thank you for your purchase $payer_email. Your total was $".$payment_amount."          for $duration hour 
    with $usercount users.  Previously paid: ".$status->paid;

    mail ($payer_email , $subject , $message);

}
```

Alternatively get_row also works like this

```
    $paidstatus = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT paid FROM wp_bbbiller WHERE txn_id = '$txn_id'");

    $subject = 'Test e-mail';
    $message = "Thank you for your purchase $payer_email. Your total was $".$payment_amount." for $duration hour 
    with $usercount users.  Previously paid: ".$paidstatus->paid;

    mail ($payer_email , $subject , $message);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use [get_results](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb). Then use a while loop to set your status from the database as a variable for insertion into the email.

Also what do you want it to say in your message where you currently have the variable `$paidstatus`. You wouldn't want a 0 or 1 like your database is storing would you? You need to create an if statement to set the value of the variable depending on its status in your database.

Comment: Yes thank you get_results works.  I created a new answer to highlight the proper code.  Also to answer your question about storing it as a 0 or 1, I don't intend to actually use it in the e-mail, I intend to use it in some logic but I wanted to make sure the variable was being passed out of the database correctly, and the only way I know of to output a script like this so I can check it is to an e-mail.