# Foreach loop issue with array PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, wordpress

I'm trying to match my array with a entries in a table and retrieving the ID of the entry.  So I have the following array called $features.

```
    Array
     (
     [0] => Body Side Moldings: Body-Color
     [1] => Door Handle Color: Black
     [2] => Exhaust Tip Color: Stainless-Steel
     [3] => Front Bumper Color: Chrome
     [4] => Grille Color: Chrome Surround
     [5] => Mirror Color: Black
     [6] => Rear Bumper Color: Chrome
     [7] => Steering Ratio: 16.7
     )
```

The foreach code that I'm using is this:

```
foreach($features as $key => $value) 
    {
        $results = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id FROM terms WHERE name = '$value'");
        echo "$results";
    }
```

Now what is happening is that I get the first ID to echo fine, then nothing after that.  I did then tried to echo $value and it printed all my values in the array fine.  I manually did a search for those terms in the 'terms' table and they come up fine.

What exactly am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you show more php code so we can see the `fetch` or wp equiv

Comment: Try this to see if this gives expected result : `$results = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT term_id FROM terms WHERE name = 'Mirror Color: Black'" ); var_dump( $results );`

Comment: It gave:  
string(3) “233”  8 times.  So it's matching the array variables and returning the ID fine.  But when I set the WHERE clause through the loop variable, it just returns the first ID, then the rest return NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using WordPress' [get_results()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) function instead of get_var(). Also see this similar [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298739/wpdb-get-var-isnt-working-for-me).

```
foreach ($features as $key => $value) {
     $results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT term_id FROM terms WHERE name = '$value'");    

     // PRINTING RESULTS PER EACH ITEM OF ARRAY
     echo $value . " RESULTS:\n";
     foreach ($results as $output) {
         echo $output->term_id;
     }
}
```

Comment: I tried this method and it prints out all my array values fine, but it's definitely not giving me the term_id at all now.  Before it would just give me the first one and then null's after.

Comment: So nothing outputs with last echo statement? Any errors? Consider running the query outside code and see your results.

Answer (score 0):

I think you try to concatenate the value. Like this:

```
foreach($features as $key => $value) {
   $results = $wpdb->get_var("SELECT term_id FROM terms WHERE name ='".$value."'");
}

    echo "$results";
```

Comment: Using this still gives me the same issue.  It gives me the 'term_id' of the first $value, then it's all blank after that.  I added a comma to the echo and the output was this: 476,,,,,,,,

Comment: what exactly are you going to find? the value or id?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [get_results](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) and [prepare](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), something similar to:

```
$placeholdersFeatures = implode(', ', array_fill(0, count($features), '%s'));
$results = $wpdb->get_results($wpdb->prepare('SELECT term_id FROM terms WHERE name IN (' . $placeholdersFeatures . ')', $features));

foreach ($results as $feature) {
    echo $feature->term_id;
}
```

This will improve your performance a little.